# curl result within a div not show up

Tags: javascript, php, curl, show

I hope someone can help..

I'm trying to get shipping information from other site. 
The tracking result is fine on the original site by using http://www.cekresi.com/?noresi=MXGAA08491431715#

But when I use @file_get_contents to show it on my site, it doesn't want to show up.

Here is the code:

```
$data=@file_get_contents('http://www.cekresi.com/?noresi=MXGAA08491431715#');
echo $data;
```

===

and for more spesific result within a div:

```
$data=@file_get_contents('http://www.cekresi.com/?noresi=MXGAA08491431715#');
$begin='-- Start Hasil pencarian -->';
$end='-- Akhir Hasil pencarian -->';
$content=explode($begin, $data);
$contents=explode($end, $content[1]);
$result=$contents[0];
echo $result;
```

Do I have to include all the javascript source from that page?
Thank for any help!

Comment: firebug - check the *net* tab and you will see why

Comment: By using `@` in front of `file_get_contents`, you are suppressing any error that may occur.  If you remove the `@`, do you get an error message?

Comment: Hi Dagon, can you more detail what i have to check in the net tab? Thanks

Comment: Hi Moshe, no error at all. Just the same output

Answer (score 0):

The website to which you are linking uses JavaScript to load the main page content. If you look at the original page source, you will see the following:

```
<!-- Start Hasil pencarian -->
<div class="container">
    <div align="center">
      <div style="width:728px;" align="left">
    <div class="row">
                <div id="results" style="display:none;">
                </div>
        </div>
   </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- Akhir Hasil pencarian -->
```

The content of `<div id="results">` is loaded using JavaScript.  If you want that content, you'll have to figure out how to do it the same way that they are doing it.

Note that while the website is deliberately obfuscating the method they use to retrieve data from the server, they do offer an API which you can use to get the data.  See http://www.cekresi.com/api.php for details.

Comment: They have discontinued the API service long time ago, that's why I need to write my own code to get the result. Until now i cannot figure out how they retrieve the data.